# Looping through a list to webscrape

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am attempting to webscrape information for every postcode in Australia. This is a sample page of one postcode https://www.domain.com.au/suburb-profile/drummoyne-nsw-2047

Unfortunately I do not have the entire postcode list that sits within this website so I have had to use an external source to create a list to run through, however the external source contains a bunch of postcodes/suburbs that don't exist on the website I am webscraping.

I am currently looping through my list but whenever it hits a postcode that doesnt exist on the domain website it gives me "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404." which is fine but the issue is it stops the loop from running and I have to manually start it again by deleting the suburb that does not exist.

Is there a smarter way to do this where I can make note of which rows from my loop list are erroring out but continue the loop so that I can delete all the relevant rows at the very end, rather than deleting them one at a time every time the code errors out?

Below is my code

```
postcodes <- read.csv("C:/postcode list.csv")

data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 0))

for (i in 1:nrow(postcodes)){ 

url <- paste0("https://www.domain.com.au/suburb-profile/",postcodes[i,])

page <- read_html(url)

contentnodes <- page %>%

  html_element("div.css-0") %>%

  html_table() %>%

  `[`(-1)

contentnodes$suburb <- paste0(postcodes[i,])

 data <- rbind(data,contentnodes)
  
  print(i)

  Sys.sleep(6)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
codelist <- c('pyrmont-nsw-2009', 'gobbledigook', 'darwin-city-nt-0800')
```

Create a helper function to return an HTML-Document with error text.
Not strictly needed, but this way the downstream processing steps have to deal with HTML output only:

```
library(htmltools)

create_error_doc <- \(txt) {htmlTemplate(text_ = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>' |>
                                           paste0(txt) |>
                                           paste0('</body></html>')
                                         ) |> renderDocument()
}
```

process code list, *catching errors*, and store result:

```
library(rvest)

the_docs <- 
  codelist |>
  Map(f = \(code) tryCatch(read_html(sprintf('https://www.domain.com.au/suburb-profile/%s', code)),
                           error = \(e) read_html(create_error_doc('unknown postcode'))
                           )
      )
```

```
## > str(the_docs)
## List of 3
##  $ pyrmont-nsw-2009   :List of 2
##   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
##   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
##  $ gobbledigook       :List of 2
##   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
##   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
##  $ darwin-city-nt-0800:List of 2
##   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
##   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```